# Make wampserver online on internet without port forwarding

Tags: wampserver, dialogflow-es

I want to make my wampserver online to make it accessible by api.ai webhook. I tried it by port forwarding but I am not able to do that. Is there some other method to do make wampserver online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered it before, but answering it again for your convenience.

Run your local host server as you do.

Then download the following utility.

https://ngrok.com/download

Then unzip it and you will get a ngrok binary.

Then run, ngrok http portnu

here port number is the one where your local webserver(wampserver) is listening.

On running the above command, ngrok will provide a http as well as a https public url. Use that public url as your fulfillment logic  on dialog flow console(api.ai). And now your wampserver is online and accessible by the webhook.

Comment: but it doesn't work with virtualhost domain, I tried it. it will instead tunneling the wampserver home page instead of virtualhost domain like http://someweb.test